# LaTeX symbol for a particular chi-squared

Tags: symbols

In the book *An Introduction to Error Analysis: The Study of Uncertainties in Physical Measurements* by J. R.Taylor I find the following formula:

[image]

In LaTeX, does it exist any symbol for [image] shown above?

Comment: Is $\tilde\chi^2$ close enough?

Comment: @MikeRenfro You mean this probably: `$\tilde{\chi}^2$`

Comment: That is more correct in the general case, but for a single character, aren't they equivalent?

Comment: @MikeRenfro For this particular case, yes... but it is always a good practice to keep everything affecting what it should, specially if this is going to go inside a macro :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\[\tilde{\chi}^2=\frac{1}{d}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(O_k - E_k)^2}{E_k}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]